# Fatal: Syntax error, ")"expected but identifier found

Tags: freepascal

```
TOTAL [X] := 
    (0.1 tomat*harga tomat ) + (0.2 cabe*harga cabe) + (0.3 kol*harga kol)+ 
    (0.4 ikan*hargaikan)+  (0.5 tahun*hargatahu) + (0.6 tahu*harga tahu);
```

Answer (score 1):

Each of the six sub expressions has syntax errors. For instance

```
0.1 tomat*harga tomat
```

You can't omit operators like you do in maths. So perhaps what you meant is

```
0.1 * tomat * harga * tomat
```

Or perhaps `harga tomat` is meant to be a single variable. Variable names cannot contain spaces. So you'd need to rename it without a space.

Comment: you have email dude

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320815/fatal-syntax-error-expected-but-identifier-found?noredirect=1#comment1051313_320815                                                           can you correcting my coding on this website . idk how to post my coding on there

Comment: No, dude, no email. You.can work this out with reference to a good book or online course.